# Spring MVC Binding: How to bind ArrayList<...>?

Tags: spring, binding, spring-mvc

I've got a DTO (bean) with `ArrayList` field:

```
public MyDTO {
  ...
  private List<MyThing> things;
  ...
  ... getters, setters and so on
}
```

In my initBinder I have:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
  ...
  binder.registerCustomEditor(List.class, "things", new PropertyEditorSupport() {
    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
       List<MyThing> things = new ArrayList<MyThings>;

       // fill things array with data from text
       ...


       // On that stage things value is correct!
       super.setValue(things);
    }
  });
}
```

And in my controller request method:

```
@RequestMapping({"save"})
public ModelAndView doSaveMyDTO(@ModelAttribute MyDTO myDTO) {
  // very strange myDTO comes here=(
}
```

The problem is that while I'm in `registerCustomEditor` staff the `things` array is ok.

But when I get to the `doSaveMyDTO` method - `MyDTO.things` looks like Array of one element arrays of actual values:

Expected (things in initBinder):

```
[value1, value2, value3]
```

Get in doSaveMyDTO (myDTO.getThings()):

```
[[value1], [value2], [value3]]
```

Why? Please explain...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the request is correctly formed (`things=v1&things=v2&things=v3` or `things=v1,v2,v3`), spring's built-in converters should properly convert it to a `List` - no need to register your own.

If your input is JSON, then you'd need `@RequestBody` instead of `@ModelAttribute`

Comment: unfortunately I've got my list as a json string.. Anyway, thanks for your advice - I'll try to make it in your way...

Comment: ah, json is another thing. How does your json look like? And for it I think you many need @RequestBody