# CustomBinder in Spring MVC for processing list of objects

Tags: spring-mvc

I have spring mvc form from which i am submitting values of a cusomized object A. The customized object A has one of its field as a list of another object B.

In the controller, I can see the size of list of object B but it is throwing error message of 
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List'

Now I have created a class CustomBinder which is following

```
public class CustomBinder extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    private List<b> listOfb;

    public CustomBinder(List<b> listOfb){
        this.listOfb = listOfb;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setValue(listOfb);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsText() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getAsText();
    }
}
```

and in the controller,  I have registered the custombinder

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(Object target, WebDataBinder binder)
{
    binder.setValidator(this.productUniqueValidator);
    A a = (A) target;
    List<B> b= a.getLstOfB;
    binder.registerCustomEditor(List.class,"bs" ,new CustomBinder(b));
}
```

I am still getting a error message...Not sure what i am doing wrong !!

Comment: I have referenced following link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794847/spring-mvc-binding-how-to-bind-arraylist?rq=1    But i am not understanding that how to fill array with data from text

Comment: If you're just posting a form that needs to get converted to a class with a list of simple objects, you shouldn't need a custom binder, you can just use `@ModelAttribute` on your controller method parameter.

Comment: What do you need `CustomBinder` for?